# End condition for recursion involving walking the filesystem

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I'm making a helper tool to compare the directory structures of two directories using python.  I have this completed in a single threaded manner (where it walks through the entire directory structure of both input directories and compares the output as it goes) and now I'm looking to extend to using multi threading and a queue.  The code I've written below is the simplest I think I can make my problem; it recursively walks through all subdirectories for a given directory (`/tmp` in the example).  The problem is that I don't know how I can detect that the job has been finished.  I currently hold the threads with a `time.sleep(40)` call, but that doesn't accomplish my goal.

Any suggestions as to how I can detect when the entire filesystem has been seen? Or maybe a suggestion on how to redesign my approach?

NOTE to address current comments: The threads don't complete, they currently are on a `while True` loop, so `thread.join()` doesn't work in this situation. As well, the way I was accomplishing my goal when single threaded was to iterate over `os.walk()`, but I have processing to do at each directory and would like to queue up the work to be accomplished by threads as opposed to a single thread

Thanks

```
from os import sep, walk
import threading
import time
import logging
import queue

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='(%(threadName)-9s) %(message)s',)

class ConsumerThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            if not q.empty():
                receivedPath = q.get()
                path, dirs, files = next(walk(receivedPath))
                logging.debug('Got ' + str(path))

                #Do heavy computation

                for dir in dirs:
                    #construct path: "path/to/current/directory" + "/" + "sub_directory"
                    item = path + sep + dir 
                    q.put(item)
                    logging.debug('Putting ' + str(item))

q = queue.Queue()
def main():
    numThreads = 20
    for consumerNum in range(1, numThreads + 1):
        ConsumerThread().start()
    initialPath = '/tmp'
    q.put(initialPath)
    time.sleep(40)

main()
```

Comment: `thread.join()` will wait for the thread to complete before returning. Why are you using threading for this though?

Comment: Can't you just iterate over the result of `os.walk()`? I don't see why anything related to end conditions is necessary. Also, writing just `return` is odd, and probably unidiomatic. Either return something, or don't return.

Comment: The threads don't complete, they currently are on a `while True` loop, so `thread.join()` doesn't work in this situation.  As well, the way I was doing it single threaded was to iterate over `os.walk()`, but I have processing to do at each directory and would like to queue up the work to be accomplished by threads as opposed to a single thread.

Comment: 'I have processing to do at each directory' That seems crucial to your question, can you elaborate? Multiprocessing might be more appropriate for the task.

Comment: Hopefully this makes sense: So I have two targets for the comparison, lets say we're comparing `drive1` to `drive2`.  I walk through both `drive1` and `drive2` by accessing directories that exist on both drives.  When I reach a directory, I compare metadata of the files in that directory to metadata in the same directory on the other drive.  I do the same with subdirectories to decide which ones I want to enter.  Then I add those subdirectories to the processing queue to be processed next.

It's essentially BFS, but parallel. I don't know the size of the BFS tree so I don't know when to stop

Comment: @MichaelHackman Can you elaborate a bit more? I don't understand this part: "When I reach a directory, I compare metadata of the files in that directory to metadata in the same directory on the other drive. I do the same with subdirectories to decide which ones I want to enter." Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you want the two (or more) processes to iterate through the file tree at the exact same pace? It might be helpful if you shared the metadata comparison code, or at least an explanation of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I the example terminate by introducing a separate counter `queueSize` (protected by `queueSizeLock`) that tracks how many entries are left in the tree as it discovers them.  Once that counter hits 0 then the entire tree has been traversed, so it notifies the main thread using a conditional variable `ProcessingFinished`.  Additionally it sets all threads to `daemon` mode so that main can just `return` once processing is finished and not worry about trying to unblock threads that are waiting on the queue in `q.get()`.

I can't imagine this is an optimal solution, but it worked for what I needed.

Globals and imports:

```
from os import sep, walk
import threading
import time
import logging
import queue

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='(%(threadName)-9s) %(message)s',)

queueSizeLock = threading.Lock()
queueSize = 1
ProcessingFinished = threading.Condition()
q = queue.Queue()
```

The class:

```
class ConsumerThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        global queueSize
        while True:
            if not q.empty():
                receivedPath = q.get()
                path, dirs, files = next(walk(receivedPath))
                logging.debug('Got ' + str(path))

                #heavy processing here

                with queueSizeLock:
                    for dir in dirs:
                        #construct path: "path/to/current/directory" + "/" + "sub_directory"
                        item = path + sep + dir 
                        q.put(item)
                        logging.debug('Putting ' + str(item))

                    '''
                    We have finished with this queue entry, so we subtract 1 
                    from the queueSize.  We have also found len(dirs) new entries 
                    for the queue, so we add that to queueSize
                    '''
                    queueSize += len(dirs) - 1

                    #tell the main thread that all processing is done
                    #can only happen once all dirs have been exhausted
                    if queueSize == 0:
                        with ProcessingFinished:
                            ProcessingFinished.notify()
```

main:

```
def queueEmpty():
        return queueSize == 0
def main():
    numThreads = 20
    for consumerNum in range(1, numThreads + 1):
        c = ConsumerThread()
        c.daemon = True
        c.start()

    initialPath = '/tmp'
    q.put(initialPath)

    with ProcessingFinished:
        ProcessingFinished.wait_for(queueEmpty)
        return 0

main()
```